# JPA Query with subquery in ORDER clause

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, aggregate

I have two Tables, let's call them Person and Interest. A Person can have many interests. What I'm trying to do now is to generate a list of persons which is ordered by the amount of interests they have. I'm not interested in how many interests each person has, I only want to have the list ordered in that way (I still want to have the entire Person entity from the query)

In plain SQL this would be a query like:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(i.id) as cnt FROM person p, interest i WHERE p.id = i.person_id ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

But I cannot figure out how to get such a query in JPA. I tried the following:

```
Join<Person, Interest> interests = rootPerson.join("interests", JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(builder.desc(builder.count(interests)))
```

But this does not produce the right data.

I also tried to write a subquery but I'm not sure how I can use a subquery in the ORDER by clause.

Any ideas?
Thanks ;)

Comment: How would your SQL work without grouping on the person?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you've shown has a 1:1 from Interests to Person, so I assume your object model would have a Person entity with a 1:M back to interest on collection 'interests'.  If so, JPQL would be:
  "Select p from Person p order by size(p.interests)".  The size might not be allowed directly in the order by clause, so you might have to use "Select p, count(p.interests) as cnt from Person p order by cnt" to more closely match your SQL.  If this works, it can easily be translated to criteria.